# onKeyDown in a service? (Global Hot Keys)

Tags: android, onkeydown

What I'm basically trying to achieve is custom global hot keys or in other words 'things will happen when I push certain buttons no matter which program is currently on top'.
I assume a service is needed.

I have a quick and dirty test that just tells me what has been pressed that will work if it is the active window.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    char pop;
    pop = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
    Toast.makeText(this, Character.toString(pop) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

But obviously if I change window or go into a text box it doesn't work.  If I stick it directly into a service (or an imputmethodservice) and launch said service nothing happens. (Some permissions required maybe?)
Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?  Or a better way of capturing which button is pressed?

Thanks!

Comment: hiii
if u hv a workaround for this then plz let me knw.

Comment: @Vincent Romain Guy works in Android team, he said this is [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3455094/942821). And Fizz, could you please accept Romain's answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an Android Service that listens for hardware key presses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986337/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-service-that-listens-for-hardware-key-presse)

Answer (score 19):

You cannot do this :)

Comment: Even in an accessibility application? There's no way to react to button or softkey presses in a service?

Comment: @Romain Guy - Sir, what if on pressing home i would like to set the screen on? How would samsung note II be doing it?

Comment: @Romain Guy Why not sir?

Comment: @Romain How nougat on my nexus 6p listens to camera on double click?

Comment: Mmmm. I feel that 'cannot' instead of can't and the slightly pass-ag smiley means "You can, but you ought not to.". Ha ha! :)

Comment: @amfcosta I'm pretty sure it's possible via accessibility service. A lot of things are possible there...

Answer (score 7):

## This requires Lollipop (v5.0/API 21) or higher

My goal was to adjust system volume from a Service, so this will only listen for the rocker. Any action can be taken on press though.

It will override volume key action, so using it globally may not be desired.

```
public class VolumeKeyController {

    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession;
    private final Context mContext;

    public VolumeKeyController(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    private void createMediaSession() {
        mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(mContext, KeyUtil.log);

        mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(new Builder()
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 0)
                .build());
        mMediaSession.setPlaybackToRemote(getVolumeProvider());
        mMediaSession.setActive(true);
    }

    private VolumeProviderCompat getVolumeProvider() {
        final AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int STREAM_TYPE = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
        int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE);
        int maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(STREAM_TYPE);

        return new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_RELATIVE, maxVolume, currentVolume) {
            @Override
            public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
                // Volume Up = AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, Volume Down = AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, Release = AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME
                // Replace with your action, if you don't want to adjust system volume
                if (direction == AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE) {
                    audio.adjustStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE,
                            AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                }
                else if (direction == AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER) {
                    audio.adjustStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE,
                            AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                }
                setCurrentVolume(audio.getStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE));
            }
        };
    }

    // Call when control needed, add a call to constructor if needed immediately
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        if (mMediaSession != null) {
            mMediaSession.setActive(active);
            return;
        }
        createMediaSession();
    }

    // Call from Service's onDestroy method
    public void destroy() {
        if (mMediaSession != null) {
            mMediaSession.release();
        }
    }
}
```