# Broadcasting on some User Action?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I was wondering if I can find something on this, like if user changes the volume on his android device or presses home button twice or thrice or any number of times, then Is there any way that I can broadcast that user has performed this action, and invoke my application? It may sound strange, and ambiguous but its a thought. Any ideas, chances of possibility? Please suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

**Reason:**

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) you can see all available keycode that you can handle in android.

Now one option would be to try to catch the keyevents from a background service. But sorry to say this is not possible. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455094/931982).

> KeyEvents can only be handled by Activities as they are the interface
>   to the user pressing the keys and only when they are in the
>   foreground. Even Services that run in the background are not intended
>   to react on user input.

i dont know whether this is changed in new api as I didn't do this by myself so you can seach a bit but i dont't think there will be any solution. I think you can only get some media button event receiver to Register a component to be the sole receiver of MEDIA_BUTTON intents by using [AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver%28android.content.ComponentName%29)