# How to track mobile button(not widget button) click event

Tags: android

In Android application is it possible that when I press my mobile *(star) button(not widget button) then I can perform any particular events in my application? If it's possible, then how may I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the * key from your hardware keyboard ( on the devices that have it) you can capture it using KeyCode.

[Here you can find an extensive list of all the keys you can intercept.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

To do it:

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STAR: //here you check any key you want
    {
        //your code here
        return true;
    }
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**EDIT**

Answering your comment, I don't believe this is possible. The KeyDown/Up events are handled on Activities. And you won't have an Activity active. [Check this out!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986337/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-service-that-listens-for-hardware-key-presse)

**EDIT**

Yeah, according to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454710/onkeydown-in-a-service-global-hot-keys/3455094#3455094) you can't.

Comment: thanks.But I want that it should be worked untill our application is not uninstalled i.e. if another application is open then the event specifies on a specific button in previous application  should be worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is within your own app, then yes.

If you mean a button in any other app (I think you mean the `*` key on the dial pad), then no.