# Custom Activity class in a Cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to make a Cordova app use a custom subclass of [`CordovaActivity`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java)?

This question was originally about detecting arbitrary key events in a Cordova app.  But now I think this is impossible for the same reason it's [impossible to receive key events in a `Service`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454710/onkeydown-in-a-service-global-hot-keys/3455094).  However, I'm thinking that if I could extend `CordovaActivity`, I could override the `onKey...` methods and broadcast something on the `LocalBroadcastManager`, which could be received by a plugin.

I'm trying to capture the [`KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) that is generated from an audio jack phone handset.  We tried listening for the [`onkey...` events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) in JavaScript.  No dice.  Since neither `CordovaActivity` nor `CordovaWebView` overrides any of the `onKey...` methods, I don't know if or how the JavaScript receives any key events at all.

Comment: If you want communication between native and JS you will need to create a plugin.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I explored that avenue.  Plugins cannot override methods in the `Activity` or `WebView`, and I don't know of any other way to intercept the key events.

Comment: In other words, a plugin cannot listen for key presses for the same reason [a Service cannot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986337/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-service-that-listens-for-hardware-key-presse).

Comment: which key presses are you looking for? I think it was originally in the question, but I don't see it now.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Edited again.

Comment: I was able to use my headphone volume buttons using the cordova events `volumeupbutton` and `volumedownbutton` but the play/pause button did nothing.

Comment: I'd like to know what somebody thinks is "opinion-based" about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an "Official Rep" in the PhoneGap community forums, this was [not possible](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_and_custom_activity_class) as of July 2012.