# Is it possible to create a service that listens for Volume key (hardware) presses?

Tags: android, service, volume, keyevent

I am trying to create a service that listens Volume key events.

Whenever the volume key presses, the service should send an sms to a number, but I can't detect volume key event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) which can detect keyevents (including volume keys). You can find the keycodes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html). Good Luck!

Comment: OnKeyListener for a android.os.service? does that even work. Service is a background entity. Will it monitor onKeyDown/onKeyUp?

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 no, that's correct, you can't listen for them in a background service

Comment: i found a way, it is possible.

Comment: @rupinderjeet can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you can not listen for key presses directly in a service ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986337/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-service-that-listens-for-hardware-key-presse?rq=1)).

On an unrelated note, it is hard for me to think of a reason to do what you want aside from writing malware.