# Measuring keyboard typing speed, key-press rate in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to create an app which runs continuously in the background and does the following:
- When user opens a keybaord to type, timer starts and I log start/end time and number of characters (key-presses) typed in a given go.
I just need ideas on this (point me to an API or something) - how should I go about this - ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to get the keys the user types?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4194447/646391

Comment: I don't want to make a keylogger - I want to calculate speed of typing for the given user...This is for statistical purposes and for modeling of user's behaviour. For example in case of intrusion detection system - I want to calculate the speed of keyboard typing and if the speed is something which normal human could not match, than this is a case which raises suspicion and I would like to alert user that something abnormal is happening.

Comment: Another case of user behaviour modelling in intrusion detection is the case where an application upon its installation sends 10 consecutive sms messages to phones not listed in a phonebook - this again is a suspicious event and I would like to alert the user and give him ability to stop/uninstall the app that is doing this.

Comment: Did you find it?

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to create your own input method editor that incorporates this feature, then convince prospective users to install and switch to your input method.

Otherwise, what you want is impossible. For obvious security and privacy reasons, apps cannot spy on other apps' data input.

Comment: I'm glad Android isn't like Windows(PC), from what I read, I was assuming he wanted to make a key logger.

Comment: I don't want to make a keylogger - I want to calculate speed of typing for the given user...This is for statistical purposes and for modeling of user's behaviour. For example in case of intrusion detection system - I want to calculate the speed of keyboard typing and if the speed is something which normal human could not match, than this is a case which raises suspicion and I would like to alert user that something abnormal is happening.