# MediaSessionCompat behaviour changed in Android 12 and setPlaybackToRemote stopped working properly

Tags: android, audio, volume, android-mediasession, mediasession

Prior to Android 12, I used code below to detect physical volume buttons pressed to show my custom UI, but it stopped working on Android 12 devices and `onAdjustVolume` is never called when I press volume buttons:

```
        mediaSessionCompat = MediaSessionCompat(context, "My App")
    mediaSessionCompat?.isActive = true
    mediaSessionCompat?.setPlaybackState(
        PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1f)
        .build())
    mediaSessionCompat?.setPlaybackToRemote(object :
        VolumeProviderCompat(VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE, 7, 4) {
        override fun onAdjustVolume(direction: Int) {
            Log.v("My App", "Volume adjusted")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, check this link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201546605?pli=1

It seems like Google changed it because of "privacy changes", according to them, but it is supposed it will be reverted in the next release (nobody knows when).